# asp.net identity authenticate by link / url asp.net mvc 5

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, remote-login

I am a fearly newbie to asp.net identity framework. Have experience with simple membership provider etc.

I want to get a user authenticated by using a special url and a token with it. 
like :  http://www.website.com/urlAuth/

A user get's an email and i want to user to login/authenticate with this url

the token is active for a certain time and has a user account ands some actions attached to it.

I cannot lay my finger on how to get a user authenticated without password. I investigated a impersination scenario (i have a special impersination with authentication info in web.config) but that's not a solid solution i think.

Could some on help me to direct me to a solid solution

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need password to authenticate users in Identity. Just you need find relevant user based on token. Consider this simple example:

```cs
public ActionResult UrlAuth(string token)
{
    var userManager=HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    // imaging you have a custom token manager which return userID form token 
    string userID=_tokenManager.GetUserIDByToken(token);
    var user = userManager.FindById(userID);
    if (user != null)
    {
         var ident = userManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

         HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false }, ident);
         // authentication succeed do what you want 
         return Redirect("Wherever");
    }
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password");
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Hi Sam, This looks pretty simple! thank you for your quick reply. I will try it tomorrow!  kind regards

Comment: If you are talking about token generated by Identity, then I don't think it is possible to deduce what user has what token, as tokens are cryptographically-generated (or can this be done?). I'd suggest to pass a userId along with the token, same as the default template works with the password reset: find user by passed ID, verify the token; if token is correct, sign-in user.

Comment: @trailmax I assumed token manager and generated tokens completely independent from Identity. Maybe generated token are unique and mapped to user id. Or maybe user id already had been embedded in generated tokens. Point of this answer is how authenticate users without password as questioner asked. Generating and managing tokens is other story.

Comment: Hi, just wanted to let you know that this solution worked for me! Thank you all for answering